# Make bugs a synonym of bug?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

What about making [bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bugs) a synonym of [bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug) since the former is just the plural of the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merged.

We now have some rudimentary protection in place to prevent new "just differ by an ending s" plural (or single) tags from being created.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ready more about that protection anywhere?